# How to write a select statement for a table in postgres that is inside a schema?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a postgres DB and inside of it there are many schemas.

Each one of those schemas contains tables. For example:

Schema Name: `personal` has tables `actions_takes`, `page_views` etc

How can i write a SQL query or ActiveRecord query to query the table inside the schema?

Something like:

```
select * from actions_takes where user_id = 123;
```

I can create a model for each table and query it that way, but i want to write a script that passed a user goes over all tables and get the data for that user.

Comment: you can use dot notation like `select * from personal.actions_takes where user_id = 123;`

Comment: Awesome, thank you @Krishna

Comment: @Krishna You should post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point to specific table within a given schema using a dot notation `schema.table_name`. In your case it translates to

```
select * from personal.actions_takes where user_id = 123;
```

Answer (score 2):

in pgAdmin 4 web console should use double quotation marks like following select statement

```
SELECT "col1", "col2"
    FROM "schemaName".profile;
```

Answer (score 1):

For me this query worked : select * from schemaName."Table_Name"